# load images to go horizontally not vertically using CSS

Tags: html, css, image

im putting images on the screen (just little circles) and every time I press a button 10 more pop up. This is what is happening:

[image]

It goes underneath the previous one.

This is what I want to happen:

[image]

my CSS thus far:

```
.numbers {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 0;
}

.num p {
    color: #877000;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 16.5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    float: left;
    font:  "SourceSansProBlack",Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}


.numbers num img {
    position: relative;
}

.userNumbers {
    position: relative;
}
```

the HTML:

```
<div class="userNumbers">
 <div class="numbers">
  <div class="num"> <p> 1 </p><img src="pic.png"></div>
  <!--to 10-->
 </div>
</div>
```

How, using CSS, can I change it to go next to each other? The images are inside a div with a class. :)

basically every time the div 'numbers' is called I want to add 32px the the left of it.. not go under it. Im calling it with JavaScript btw, but that is unrelated.

Comment: Please post your code or provide a fiddle

Comment: many many different methods to accomplish this.  My favorite has to be `css-columns`:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-columns/.  But yeah, post what you've tried and what's not working for you.

Comment: added my code  :) 

I also added where I want to make the change.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the 10 first images inside a div with a property:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Then just duplicate the div with the images and it should fine.

For example,

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">
    <img id="img1" />
    ...
    <img id="img10" />
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">
    <img id="img11" />
    ...
    <img id="img20" />
</div>
```

Comment: i have it inside one. the problem is, when i duplicate it, it goes under it not next to it..

Comment: I'll edit the answer to give a more detailed explanation in a second.

Comment: @MatanLiram, I don't see `display: inline-block;` anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: @fire_head Sorry no, it doesn't.  I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: on my end it does. It works but it still does it underneath too

Comment: Is that not close to what you wanted?  Can't you figure out the rest yourself from there or are you really hopeless...?

Comment: I just dont understand why its printing it once, and then twice, and then three times. I just wanted to add it to the right of the previous one..

Comment: Okay.  So, since it is showing up to the right, it's obviously working (inline-block fixes the issue).  It's most likely a javascript issue - it depends where/how the node is being cloned/inserted.  Maybe your initial container does not have inline-block attached to it.  Maybe you're inserting the next occurrence after a block, instead of the inline-block.  The Javascript you're using matters here, because it depends where you're inserting it, and what code you're inserting.  It depends what you're cloning and etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose this kind of approach with display `flex` to dinamically add new columns. Remember that `<p>` height should be 1/10 of `#imgContainer` if you want to show 10 images per column. For instance, if you want to show 20 images per column, set parent height to 1000px or `<p>` height to 25px

```css
#imgContainer {
    max-height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
}

#imgContainer p {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

#imgContainer img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#imgContainer span {
    color: #877000;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 16.5px;
    font:  "SourceSansProBlack",Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="imgContainer">
    <p><img src="http://goo.gl/L72CdX"><span>1</span></p>
    <p><img src="http://goo.gl/L72CdX"><span>2</span></p>
    <p><img src="http://goo.gl/L72CdX"><span>3</span></p>
    <p><img src="http://goo.gl/L72CdX"><span>4</span></p>
    <p><img src="http://goo.gl/L72CdX"><span>5</span></p>
    <p><img src="http://goo.gl/L72CdX"><span>6</span></p>
    <p><img src="http://goo.gl/L72CdX"><span>7</span></p>
    <p><img src="http://goo.gl/L72CdX"><span>8</span></p>
    <p><img src="http://goo.gl/L72CdX"><span>9</span></p>
    <p><img src="http://goo.gl/L72CdX"><span>10</span></p>
    <p><img src="http://goo.gl/L72CdX"><span>11</span></p>
    <p><img src="http://goo.gl/L72CdX"><span>12</span></p>
    <p><img src="http://goo.gl/L72CdX"><span>13</span></p> 
</div>
```